# When using two authorized clients in Spring with MSAL, I get the error AADSTS65001

Tags: spring, azure

I have two authorized clients in my Spring MSAL application, like so:

```
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: ${TENANT_ID}
    client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
    client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
    authorization-clients:
      calendar-api:
        scopes:
        - ${CALENDAR_SCOPE}
      azure-api:
        scopes:
        - ${AZURE_SCOPE}
```

If I leave either one of these clients in place, I can run my application, log in, and generate clients to call the downstream resource servers. But if I enable both clients, I get the following error:

```
[invalid_grant] AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'b31490c0-4ac4-4f8c-8f8e-d5addb72271d' named 'Frontend'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: 3f003263-5eb7-4f97-b29a-fe0337d80800 Correlation ID: 4ccb19ec-8ff9-442d-b1b6-a106aa6721eb Timestamp: 2021-09-25 09:58:41Z
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer here is to add the APIs under the API Permissions page, and grant them admin consent. Once I had added this admin consent, the error disappeared.

[image]